# Consuming API Calls

Tags: javascript, soap-api, home-page-component

I am using the following script to retrieve the records from a custom object using javascript

```
<script src="/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
-------------------------------script--------------------------------------
 var result = sforce.connection.query('Select name,.. from customObject__c where conditions');
 var customRecord = result.getArray("records");
-------------------------------script-----------------------------------------
```

This code is working fine and I added this script in my homepage component.
But the issue is whenever a page loads, homepage component executed and consume 1 api call (may be more than 1) weather conditions met or not.

So if a user refresh all about 100 times a day then nearly 100 Api will consume.

I am looking to reduce the wastage of api calls.
Is there any possible solution to reduce api calls?

Answer (score 1):

You are querying salesforce everytime when page loads by using sforce.connection.query.
That will surely count in API call.

Comment: Thanks sagar. Is there any possible alternative approach to query on a salesforce object from javascript without using soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js library?

Comment: I think the answer is no. Because seems like you need to have most recent data everytime the home page loads and this will need to query salesforce .And as you are doing your operations in javascript you need to have connection with salesforce using this library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @remoteAction static methods to retrieve the data and pass into VF page.
I am not sure what you does after retrieving the record whether you updating or displaying into HTML table. Here you can go for more details.

[Click here for more details](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2114/passing-variables-from-controller-to-page-using-remoteaction)

Comment: No i am not doing any updation after retrieving the records, i am just using some conditional logic based upon the values getting from the records.
The link you shared showing how values are coming from controller to vf page using @remoteAction but as i already mentioned that i am using JavaScript in homepage component.
Is it possible to use such kind of approach in homepage component?

Comment: Oh! Sorry I dint read carefully that you using homepage component. You can use a VF page and appends it as Iframe in your component. So when page will load your Iframe will load every time refreshed data.